# Bootstrap right column go to upper when small

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to know is there possible in bootstrap change col right go to upper when small? Default column in upper when small is left column.

I want like this:

--1--  --2--  --3--

when small like this:

--3--

--2--

--1--

this is my original code in bootstrap:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814508/order-columns-through-bootstrap4

Answer (score 3):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/41/

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8">
        1
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was just about to post the same - this is the best solution IMO

Answer (score 0):

You could put the third div first use the push and pull in bootstrap to move them around at larger screen sizes.

Here's someone with a similar problem:

[Reverse grid arrangment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924426/reverse-grid-arrangment)

And here's the documentation for push and pulling in bootstrap:
 http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

You can add multiple "column types" to a class. You can use the following column types:

1. .col-xs-*, for screens smaller than 768px wide
2. .col-sm-*, for screens above 768px wide
3. .col-md-*, for screens above 992px wide
4. .col-lg-*, for screens above 1200px wide

References:

- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro
- https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/