# Order columns through Bootstrap4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid

I have 3 columns which I want to order in different ways on desktop and mobile.

Currently, my grid looks like this:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

In the mobile view I want to have the following output:

```
1-3-2
```

Unfortunately I don't get how to solve this with the `.col-md-push-*` and `.col-md-pull-*` classes in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: It is described in the docs: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#example-column-ordering

Comment: col-xx-push-*and col-xx-pull-* are the same like bootstrap 3. Do you want the grid for 'md' and above 1-2, other row 3 and for 'sm' and below 1-3-2?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

**2021 - Bootstrap 5**

The responsive ordering classes are now `order-first`, `order-last` and `order-0` - `order-5`

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/XLuC2eGQND)

**2018 - Bootstrap 4**

The responsive [ordering classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes) are now `order-first`, `order-last` and `order-0` - `order-12`

<strike>The Bootstrap 4 **push** **pull** classes are now `push-{viewport}-{units}` and `pull-{viewport}-{units}` and the `xs-` infix has been removed. To get the desired 1-3-2 layout on mobile/xs would be: [Bootstrap 4 push pull demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/OmrcmepbUp)</strike> (This only works pre 4.0 beta)

---

**Bootstrap 4.1+**

Since Bootstrap 4 is flexbox, it's easy to change the order of columns. The cols can be ordered from `order-1` to `order-12`, responsively such as `order-md-12 order-2` (last on `md`, 2nd on `xs`) relative to the parent `.row`.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card card-body">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-12 order-2 order-md-12">
            <div class="card card-body">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 col-md-6 order-3">
            <div class="card card-body">2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: [Change order using `order-*` classes](https://www.codeply.com/go/Lmy5dG7C33)

Desktop (larger screens):
[image]

Mobile (smaller screens):
[image]

It's also possible to change column order using the [flexbox direction utils](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#direction)...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row flex-column-reverse flex-md-row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            1st on mobile
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: [Bootstrap 4.1 Change Order with Flexbox Direction](https://www.codeply.com/go/6vWQN2ocxe)

---

*Older version demos*
[demo - alpha 6](https://www.codeply.com/go/zIpTgyHfJh)
[demo - beta (3)](https://www.codeply.com/go/dNtWO26nQv)

[**See more Bootstrap 4.1+ ordering demos**](https://www.codeply.com/go/SXtwk690Lx)

---

**Related**
[Column ordering in Bootstrap 4 with push/pull and col-md-12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247873/column-ordering-in-bootstrap-4-with-push-pull-and-col-md-12)
[Bootstrap 4 change order of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292170/bootstrap-4-change-order-of-columns/45302093#45302093)

A-C-B A-B-C

Comment: @Alireza - The `order-*` classes can't be used multiple times. That's how it works. From the docs.. *"These classes are responsive, so you can set the order by breakpoint (e.g., .order-1.order-md-2). Includes support for 1 through 12 across all five grid tiers."*

Comment: @Zim So `order-2 order-md-12` classes cannot be used together?

Comment: No, they *can* be used together.

Comment: @Zim `order-md-1 order-sm-2` and `order-1 order-sm-2` don't work. I'm doing it manually

Comment: They work if you're using the version indicated above https://www.codeply.com/go/23VFxwWTdP. Also, I don't know what you're trying to accomplish which is most likely different than the original question for which my answer applies. Remember cols are relative to each other in the same row.

Comment: @Zim, OP(@Cray)  is asking for order 1-3-2 on mobile. Your original answer shows it correctly( now crossed out) but modified answer for bootstrap shows 1-2-3 on mobile. Would you be able to fix that?

Comment: @Zim, Actually the above code is correct but the picture and the **2018 Update Bootstrap 4.0+**  [demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/Lmy5dG7C33) is not showing 1-3-2 order

Comment: @Dush it does work in 4.0, but it wouldn't work that way in 4.0 alpha as explained above

Answer (score 29):

This can also be achieved with the CSS "Order" property and a media query.

Something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #first {
        order: 2;
    }
    #second {
        order: 4;
    }
    #third {
        order: 1;
    }
    #fourth {
        order: 3;
    }
}
```

CodePen Link: https://codepen.io/preston206/pen/EwrXqm

Comment: I couldn't get order with bootstrap classes just for mobile. This did work, thanks

Answer (score 5):

even this will work:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-6 order-1">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 col-sm-4  col-md-6 order-3">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 col-sm-4  col-md-12 order-2">
                    3
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Bootstrap 3, so i don't know if there is an easier way to do it Bootstrap 4 but this css should work for you:

```
.pull-right-xs {
    float: right;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
   .pull-right-xs {
      float: left;
   }
}
```

...and add class to second column:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6 pull-right-xs">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Ohh... it looks like what i was writen above is exacly a .**pull-xs-right** class in Bootstrap 4 :X Just add it to second column and it should work perfectly.

Comment: Ops... i done mistake in style code :X Try now. And if it wouldn't work, try adding !important to float.

Comment: It's the same. I've worked with the .pull-xs-right class from Bootsrap 4.

Answer (score -1):

Since column-ordering doesn't work in Bootstrap 4 beta as described in the code provided in the revisited answer above, you would need to use the following (as indicated in the codeply 4  Flexbox order demo - alpha/beta links that were provided in the answer).

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="card card-block">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-12  flex-md-last">
        <div class="card card-block">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-md-6 ">
        <div class="card card-block">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note however that the "Flexbox order demo - beta" goes to an alpha codebase, and changing the codebase to Beta (and running it) results in the divs incorrectly displaying in a single column -- but that looks like a codeply issue since cutting and pasting the code out of codeply works as described.

Answer (score -4):

You can do two different container one with mobile order and hide on desktop screen, another with desktop order and hide on mobile screen

Comment: It would work, but it's unnecessary data duplication. You can do it with manipulation of float parametr (and propabbly some other ways too).