# Bootstrap 4 right Column on top on mobile view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, bootstrap-4

I have a **Bootstrap 4** Page like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        A
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
       B
    </div>
</div>
```

Looks like:

```
-----
|A|B|
-----
```

So if I look at it on a mobile Device, the Column A is on top, but I want the B on top. Is this possible? I tried it with push an pull, but it didn't work Because I'm using Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column ordering in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814508/column-ordering-in-bootstrap-4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Bootstrap 4 you can use the following classes.

order-first, order-last and order-0 - order-12

on your element.

Have a look here: [Column ordering in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814508/column-ordering-in-bootstrap-4)

Comment: add ***order-sm-first*** class for last element

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers gave a code example showing how `order-first` works, so here you go:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        A
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 order-first order-md-last">
       B
    </div>
</div>
```

In desktop view (`md`, `lg` and `xl`) it will use `order-md-last` to preserve the current behavior (B below A)

In mobile view (`xs` and `sm`) it will now use `order-first` to order B *above* A.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        A
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
       B
    </div>
</div>
```

The Bootstrap grid system has four classes `col-xs`, `col-sm`, `col-md`, `col-lg`. That classes can be combined to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.

Comment: tried. it works . Also works if we examine the nodes. I use pug to code web app instead of html. Padding is often a headache to me.