# Bootstrap 4 Beta: responsive rows "1, 2, 3" to "2, 1, 3"

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

So the following worked on 4.alpha but I am not having any luck figuring it out on 4.beta

I am using a `col-3 | col-6 | col-3` row layout.

When the browser is `medium` *(desktop)* or larger I want that layout.

When the browser is smaller than `medium`, I would like:

- The `col-md-6` *(#2)* div to be at the top row
- The `col-md-3` *(#1)* directly below it
- The `col-md-3` *(#3)* on the very bottom row

Here is the code that I had for 4.alpha that worked:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">#1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 flex-first flex-md-unordered">#2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 flex-third flex-md-unordered">#3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the method to get this to go `2|1|3` on mobile devices??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column ordering in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814508/column-ordering-in-bootstrap-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bootstrap 4 beta 3 this feature is provided by the `.order-` classes. In the docs you can find them in the [Reordering](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering) section.

So, in your concrete case it would look like this:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 order-2 order-md-1">#1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 order-1">#2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 order-2">#3</div>
    </div>
</div>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Note: I'm not aware of the `-unordered` class suffix, and in fact, the [css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.css) available from the official Bootstrap cdn does not contain any classes like that.

Comment: Ah, that `order-md-1` is what I was missing in my testing. I had the `order-#` but not that `order-md-1` on the #1 row. Thanks @dferenc Marked as answered.