# Bootstrap 4x: Can you change column order based on viewport size?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap is great for its ability to reorder columns regardless of the HTML structure, however I would like to have a different order of these particular elements when at a smaller viewport size (e.g. Mobile).

The structure of the HTML is something like:

```
[Page Content]
[Nav Links]
[Sidebar]
```

And using Bootstrap 4.1 and its order-first/order-last classes on [Nav Links] and [Sidebar] respectively, the page appropriately displays like so:

```
[Nav Links] [Page Content] [Sidebar]
```

However, what I would LIKE to happen when the viewport shrinks below the break threshold, for [Nav Links] to go back underneath [Page Content] like a good little fella.  The Bootstrap documentation does not seem to go into this sort of implementation, and though I found a similar question on here for a previous Bootstrap version, the described methods use classes that have since been removed.  Anyone have any suggestions?

(Actual code follows, just in case I missed something)

```
<div class="row">
    <main class="col-sm-8">
        [Page Content]
    </main>
    <nav class="col-sm-2 px-3 order-first">
        [Nav Links]
    </nav>
    <section class="col-sm-2 order-last">
        [Sidebar Content]
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use the order classes for the grid (which uses flexbox) https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes

```
<div class="row">
    <main class="col-sm-8 order-md-2">
        [Page Content]
    </main>
    <nav class="col-sm-2 px-3 order-md-1">
        [Nav Links]
    </nav>
    <section class="col-sm-2 order-md-3">
        [Sidebar Content]
    </section>
</div>
```

To order at breakpoints

Comment: Aha!  I needed `order-sm-#` instead but works like a charm!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This [question has been answer before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814508/column-ordering-in-bootstrap-4#answer-43069703) by [Zim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171456/zim)

Yes you can change the [column order based on viewport size](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes) using order-{size}-{order number}.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card card-body">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-12 order-2 order-md-12">
            <div class="card card-body">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 col-md-6 order-3">
            <div class="card card-body">2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```