# How can I display column 2 first in mobile view before column 1

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

[image]

I have a page where row is divided into two columns. In mobile view, I want to display column 2 first and then column 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order columns through Bootstrap4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814508/order-columns-through-bootstrap4)

Comment: This make my designing layout different.

Comment: please check the below snippet if it works

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? If yes,you can do that using `order-sm-**`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 order-sm-12">column 2</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 order-sm-1">column 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```