# how to change position of the list in the navbar

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

So I'm really new and taking this class on Udemy; but the navigation bar isn't working even though I am straight up copying the instructor at this point.

What I want it to do is that to list the list on the right side of the creen, which isn't happening.

```
<nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order columns through Bootstrap4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814508/order-columns-through-bootstrap4)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is working fine [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-bush-fyfbw?file=/index.html)

Please Check if you are using the correct CDN or version

Comment: thank you. the instructor uses Bootstrap4.0 where as I have installed Bootstrap5.0 . Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's would be the cause of problem, I checked it with bootstrap ^4.0 and it works fine

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct! Thanks :)