# Cannot get div items ordered out of sequence with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I have included the `bootstrap 3.4.1` in my `Angular 12` project and placed this HTML on my `app.component` page:

```
<div class="container">
  ...
  <div class="d-flex row">
    <div class="order-3 col">Third flex item</div>
    <div class="order-2 col">Second flex item</div>
    <div class="order-1 col">First flex item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect this to produce three lines:

```
First flex item
Second flex item
Third flex item
```

But they are ordered as displayed in the code, rather than as specified by their `order-X` class values.

What am I doing wrong?

[My full source is available here](https://github.com/HoraceBury/favuni/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Please check this if it can help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814508/order-columns-through-bootstrap4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those [utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes) belong to bootstrap 4, you can use `order-first` and `order-last` to simplify

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  ...
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="col order-last">Third flex item</div>
    <div class="col">Second flex item</div>
    <div class="col order-first">First flex item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```