# Desktop: Image left, headline and text right <vs.> Mobile: Headline, Image, Text one below the other [Flexbox/Grid Layout]

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

a layout question for the CSS professionals here:

---

**On big desktop screens, I want this layout:**

[image: Image left, headline and text right]

Two columns:

- Image 2️⃣ vertically centered in left column
- Headline 1️⃣ and text 3️⃣ both on the right side column

---

**On small mobile screens I want to switch order:**

[image: Headline, image, Text one below the other]

One column with headline, image and text one below the other:

- Headline 1️⃣ top
- image 2️⃣ middle
- text 3️⃣ bottom

With css flexbox this seems to be impossible as I cannot take out 2️⃣ on the big screen layout. Any ideas how to solve this with minimal code?

Comment: You should have shared your code. Also if you are using bootstrap, you can easily do that with `order` utility. [Check this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814508/order-columns-through-bootstrap4#:~:text=Since%20Bootstrap%204%20is%20flexbox,row%20.&text=It's%20also%20possible%20to%20change,the%20flexbox%20direction%20utils...)

Comment: @VivekK. Agree about the share of a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but the link provided is not enough to answer the question

Comment: Also, `order` is a css property, it can be usefull to solve the question using flexbox, but I wonder if a grid wouldn't be better (I'm not used to use it so I'm not sure)

Comment: @Cédric exactly the case with me, I am used to the flexbox.