# How do I change column ordering in Bootstrap on mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to change the order of my sidebar and content areas on my page.

```
<div class="col-md-3">Sidebar</div>
<div class="col-md-9">Content</div>
```

I've a hefty amount of content in my sidebar and I would like the sidebar to show under the content area on mobile instead of content under sidebar.

I've searched a few questions and I cannot seem to get the solutions to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change Bootstrap 3 column order on mobile layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout)

Comment: Tried these, they didnt work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse grid arrangment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924426/reverse-grid-arrangment)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `col-md-pull-*` and `col-md-push-*` classes. You want to set the *mobile* order in your HTML directly, then use these classes to rearrange them for desktop, ie:

```
<div class="col-md-9">Content</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-3-pull">Sidebar</div>
```

Comment: So what your saying is start at mobile and edit for full screen?

Comment: @AlexKnopp yes. Check this out for more information: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Comment: I'll look into this

Answer (score -1):

whit that code should be work, but add those clases

```
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">Content</div>
```

Comment: This does not change the stacking order. All this will do is show the columns full width at small screens.